# Delete rows except for one for every id

Tags: sql, hsqldb, delete-row

I have a dataset with multiple ids. For every id there are multiple entries. Like this:

```
--------------
| ID | Value |
--------------
| 1  |   3   | 
| 1  |   4   |
| 1  |   2   |
| 2  |   1   |
| 2  |   2   |
| 3  |   3   |
| 3  |   5   |
--------------
```

Is there a SQL DELETE query to delete (random) rows for every id, except for one (random rows would be nice but is not essential)? The resulting table should look like this:

```
--------------
| ID | Value |
--------------
| 1  |   2   |
| 2  |   1   |
| 3  |   5   |
--------------
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the given answers with HSQLDB but it refused to execute those queries for different reasons (join is not allowed in delete query, ignore statement is not allowed in alter query). Thanks to Andrew I came up with this solution (which is a little bit more circumstantial, but allows it to delete random rows):

Add a new column for random values:

```
ALTER TABLE <table> ADD COLUMN rand INT
```

Fill this column with random data:

```
UPDATE <table> SET rand = RAND() * 1000000
```

Delete all rows which don't have the minimum random value for their id:

```
DELETE FROM <table> WHERE rand NOT IN (SELECT MIN(rand) FROM <table> GROUP BY id)
```

Drop the random column:

```
ALTER TABLE <table> DROP rand
```

For larger tables you probably should ensure that the random values are unique, but this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
alter ignore table a  add unique(id);
```

Here `a` is the table name

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like hsqldb fully supports olap functions (in this case `row_number() over (partition by ...)`, so you'll need to use a derived table to identify the one value you want to keep for each ID.  It certainly won't be random, but I don't think anything else will be either.  Something like so

This query will give you the first part:
    select 
    id,
    min(value) as minval 
    from
    
    group by id

Then you can delete from your table where you don't match:

```
delete from 
        <your table> t1
        inner join 
        (
        select 
            id,
            min(value) as minval 
            from
            <your table>
            group by id
        ) t2
        on t1.id = t2.id
    and t1.value <> t2.value
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT ID, Value 
   FROM (SELECT ID, Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RN 
           FROM @Table) AS A    
WHERE A.RN = 1
```